# WSO2 - Password recovery without using captchas, emails or challenge questions

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to recover a user's password from an app that uses Soap to communicate with WS02 Identity server.

What I intend is to ask WS02 for a confirmation code to password recovery, send it myself by email to the user and when I receive the confirmation code, post it together with the new password to the WSO2 api.

I'm using the following settings:

```
Notification.Sending.Enable=false
Notification.Expire.Time=0
Notification.Sending.Internally.Managed=false
UserAccount.Recovery.Enable=true
Captcha.Verification.Internally.Managed=false
```

I tried to follow the recovery process mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Password+Recovery) but errors keep happening:

1. getCaptcha() -­ Ignored as I don't pretend a captcha
2. verifyUser() -­ Returns a key successfully.
3. sendRecoveryNotification() -­ Fails when given key from step 2: 18001 invalid confirmation code for user.
4. getCaptcha() ­- Ignored as I don't pretend a captcha
5. verifyConfirmationCode() -­ Uses key from step 2: 18001 invalid confirmation code for user.
6. updatePassword() - Uses key from step 2: 18013 Error while updating credential for user.

Is it possible to recover the password without using captchas or emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Notification.Expire.Time` to a higher value (eg, 60). This is the time (in minutes) that the key will be valid. In your case by the time you call `sendRecoveryNotification()` the key should have been expired.

Also in step 6, when calling `updatePassword()`, it should be the key from step 5 (you'll get one when you get the above fixed), not the one from step 2.

Comment: Indeed, the issue was with the Expiration Time. Thank you :)